# Trying to sava depth image with pylibfreenect2

Tags: python, kinect

it's my first time here.

I'm using pylibfreenect2 to save the images from kinect v2.

The color images are normal when saved on .JPG format, but, when I try to save the depth image, it turns all black on .JPG.

Anyone knows if I have to change the format, or do I have to change the way I save the image.

Sorry for the bad english and thanks.